# Android Java - postRotate not rotating around center?

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I believe this is more of a logic question than a java question, sorry.

My intent is rather straightforward, i want the ship to move and rotate with a matrix, with the bitmap ship1 being the center pivot of the rotation.  The code works great except the pivot is off by a strange offset.  (picture of conundrum linked at bottom)

The default value rotation at 0 works but all the other values seem to slide away from the center, with 180 being the furthest from the center.

```
centerX = playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + ship1.getWidth()/2;
centerY = playerValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + ship1.getHeight()/2;

newRotation = ((float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(fingery1 - centerY, fingerx1 - centerX)));

matrix.postRotate((newRotation - prevRotation), centerX, centerY);
prevRotation = newRotation;

        if (fingerx1 > playerX) {
            xspeed = 1;
        } else

        if (fingerx1 < playerX) {
            xspeed = 0;
        } else

        if (fingery1 > playerY) {
            yspeed = 1;
        } else

        if (fingery1 < playerY) {
            yspeed = 0;
        }

        matrix.postTranslate(xspeed, yspeed);

matrix.getValues(playerValues);
```

I tried to draw how the relation of the bitmap looks at different angles. (the blue dot is where I intend to rotate the bitmap around, the arrow pointing right is the only correct one).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yw76.png

Please let me know if you see any errors or any feedback helps! I just need a second pair of eyes on this because mine are going to explode soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider studying a good computer graphics text re matrix math.  Foley and Van Dam is always a safe bet.

The matrix A is applied to point x with multiplication Ax.  You have A = RT a rotation with translation post multiplied.  The result is RTx which is R (T x) meaning the point is translated *then* rotated, when you probably meant the opposite.

Additionally it appears you are concatenating incremental changes repeatedly. Floating point errors will accumulate, visible as worsening distortions.  Instead maintain orientation parameters x, y, theta for each ship.  These are controlled by the UI. Set the matrix from these in each rendering.  The transform will be rotation about the point (w/2, h/2) followed by translation to (x, y).  But the matrix to effect this is the translation post multiplied by the rotation!  Also you must reset the matrix for each ship.

Comment: Thanks! I really try too hard sometimes, I was looking for a more convenient way than using orientation parameters by referencing the matrix's values but they are not reliable, at least the way i'm using them.